# How can I make a Spinner with human readable options that resolves to a machine code when saving?

Tags: java, android

I have predefined category names with corresponding machine codes given to me by the client. For instance:

BLDG-EXT = Exterior Building Issues
BLDG-INT = Interior Building Issues
CUSTOD = Custodial Services

These are just three examples of about twenty. The problem is, I want my Spinner to display the human readable options (such as "Exterior Building Issues") to the user, but when the data is saved and stored into my SQLite database I want it to be saved as the machine code.

How can I do this?

Thank you,
Alex

EDIT: Here is my current implementation which does not include machine readable category names, only Strings.

Generating the Spinner (inside the onCreate() method):

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.issue_category_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.issue_categories,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
if (null != issue.get_category()) {
    spinner.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(issue.get_category()));
}
```

Saving the data on a button press:

```
private void save_issue() {
    // Save field data to current issue
    issue.set_category(((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.issue_category_spinner))
            .getSelectedItem().toString());
    issue.set_building_code(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.issue_field_building_code))
            .getText().toString().toUpperCase());
    issue.set_floor_code(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.issue_field_floor_code))
            .getText().toString().toUpperCase());
    issue.set_location(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.issue_field_location))
            .getText().toString());
    issue.set_priority((int) ((PriorityRatingBar) findViewById(R.id.issue_field_priority))
            .getRating());
    issue.set_description(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.issue_field_description))
            .getText().toString());
    // Then save the current issue to the DB
    if (update) {
        db.updateIssue(issue);
    } else {
        issue.set_audit_id(getIntent().getExtras().getLong(
                "me.alexgleason.project.Audit"));
        issue = db.addIssue(issue);
    }
    // Save image
    File image = new File(get_storage_dir(), "temp.jpg");
    image.renameTo(new File(get_storage_dir(), issue.get_uuid() + ".jpg"));
    // Toasty
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Issue Saved",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

And in strings.xml

```
<string-array name="issue_categories">
    <item>Other</item>
    <item>Paint</item>
    <item>Lighting</item>
    <item>Flooring</item>
    <item>Custodial</item>
    <item>Furniture</item>
    <item>Exterior</item>
    <item>Plumbing</item>
    <item>Signage</item>
    <item>Parking</item>
    <item>Landscaping</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: so what's stopping you from taking the internal code, looking up the human version, and displaying that?

Comment: What's the correct way to do that, though? A Spinner is populated by an adapter, so do I need to create a custom adapter to hold the categories?

Comment: Show the code with which you need help, without it we're guessing more than helping.

Comment: I added some code. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend two different arrays, with each equivalent item in the same position in each one, so you would end up doing something like this;

```
   String[] machineCodes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.machineCodes);
      String[] manCodes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.manCodes);

  //set manCodes to spinner and spinner style

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int which, long id) {
                                    String machineCode = machineCodes[which];
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I was trying to figure out how to retrieve the machine code from the Spinner at save time, but storing it when the position is changed makes perfect sense too.